# Draw video in canvas on another window

Tags: javascript, video, canvas

I have a problem to draw video in another canvas with IE, it's work fine on another webbrowser but IE do an error

```
  <body>
<video id='video' src='http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4' controls></video>
<button id='button'>Open Window</button>
<script>
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  var popup = null;
  button.onclick = function() {
    if(popup == null){
      popup = window.open("", "", "width=640,height=360");
      var canvas = popup.document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.id = 'Canvas';
      popup.document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      popup.onbeforeunload = function(){
        popup = null;
      }
      setInterval(function() {
        var temp = popup.document.getElementById('Canvas');
        if (temp != null) {
          temp.width = popup.innerWidth;
          temp.height = popup.innerHeight;
          try {
            temp.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, temp.width, temp.height);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
          }
        }
      }, 1000/30)
    }
  }
</script>
```

and when i want to draw video in this canvas, don't work in internet explorer
IE give this erreur when i catch it :

```
TypeMismatchError
  [functions]: ,
  ABORT_ERR: 20,
  code: 17,
  DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
  DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
  HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
  INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
  INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
  INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
  INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
  INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
  INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
  INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
  message: "TypeMismatchError",
  name: "TypeMismatchError",
  NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
  NETWORK_ERR: 19,
  NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
  NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
  NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
  NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9,
  PARSE_ERR: 81,
  QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22,
  SECURITY_ERR: 18,
  SERIALIZE_ERR: 82,
  SYNTAX_ERR: 12,
  TIMEOUT_ERR: 23,
  TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: <Permission refusée>,
  URL_MISMATCH_ERR: <Permission refusée>,
  VALIDATION_ERR: <Permission refusée>,
  WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: <Permission refusée>
```

Have you an idea to counter this problem ?

Comment: Your error tells that it's a security issue, they probably don't allow other frames to access canvas methods. A possible workaround would be to load the video in your popup too (doesn't need to be in the document)

Comment: If i load video in the new window, i not sure i keep synchro and i use more bandwidth, i want to use this window to get a party of this video and i need to be synchro

Comment: then 
I'm afraid you'll loose IE

Comment: I need this feature in IE ^^ because only IE can use audiotrack in video ... i  do test with method in the new window but same result. No propriety to remove this security ? or i can use Safari ...

Comment: You would need to redefine exactly what you want to do, other browsers have support for more cool features that may be useful for your project (e.g captureStream and MediaRecorder) But then, it would probably be better in a new question.

Comment: To clarify my project, i want to use this to do Multicam, for this :
 - i have a 4 video in one
 - mainplayer play a part of video
 - new window play all video and it's use to switch view
 - i need to use IE or Edge because i want to use multitrack audio ( only on IE or Safari )

Problem : draw in new window don't work on Internet Explorer or Edge

Comment: Multicam = Multi-camera ^^
stream come to mp4 file make by ffmpeg, I want to use popup to broadcast player on tv and pilot browser in pc ( for example ), for the canvas, other method exist to draw a video in new frame ?

Comment: I missed your editing of previous comment... For an alternative, I unfortunately don't have an all-done solution for you, but you may want to check [MediaSource API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource). This could allow you to have an implementation able to read multiple audio sources, in sync with the video.